# Написание функции,которая выводит на экран предпоследний элемент типизированного файла в Паскале

Tags: файлы, pascal, вывод

Добрый день! Нужна помощь в работе с типизированными файлами в Паскале. Каким образом можно написать функцию,которая обратится к предпоследнему элементу типизированного файла и выведет его на экран? Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаем, что в файл пишутся записи типа `MyRecord` (но может быть и другой, не только record ( и byte, и integer, и double), главное, - постоянного размера):

```
type
  MyRecord = record
      name: string[40];
      index:integer;
    end;

var
  f: file of MyRecord;
  dd : MyRecord; // ваш тип

begin
  Assign(f, 'трампарам.ttt');
  Reset(f);
  if FileSize(f)<2 then 
    writeln('В файле нет предпоследнего элемента')
  else
    begin
      seek(f,FileSize(f)-2);
      read(f,dd);
    end;
  writeln('Предпоследний элемент имеет имя ',dd.name);
  Сlose(f);
end.
```